# Enqueue a css using negative conditional tags

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I'm building a theme on top of purecss.io. In order to make the grid responsive I need to add [this stylesheet](http://purecss.io/start/#responsive-grids). From functions.php

```
function load_css() {

wp_enqueue_style ( 'purecss-all-not-ie', 'http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/grids-responsive-min.css', array( 'purecss' ), null );
wp_style_add_data ( 'purecss-all-not-ie', 'conditional', 'gt IE 8' );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_css' );
```

and the output is

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='purecss-new-ie-css'  href='http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/grids-responsive-min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
```

however the correct conditional tag should be `<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->`

I've found a couple of discussions [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25427) and [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16118) but I'm a bit lost as I don't understand what's the proposed solution. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug's only 4 years old so you wouldn't want to rush them would you?! A workaround is to leave out the `wp_style_add_data()` and use the `'style_loader_tag'` filter:

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {
    if ( $handle  == 'purecss-all-not-ie' ) {
        $tag = "<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->\n" . $tag . "<!--<![endif]-->\n";
    }
    return $tag;
}, 10, 2 );
```